# If statement behaves strange

Tags: php

I have 2 URLs say

```
http://localhost/xyz?language=en
http://localhost/xyz?language=es
```

for which I want to check if language parameter has something other than en/es, then it should redirect to some `http://localhost/xyz/errorpage`

For this I have below code:

```
if(isset($_GET['language'])){
    if(($_GET['language'] !== "en") || ($_GET['language'] !== "es")){
        header('Location: /xyz/errorpage'); 
    }
}
```

But practically when I execute the any of the 2 URLs or putting value of `language` parameter to something different than `en`/`es`:

```
http://localhost/xyz?language=en
http://localhost/xyz?language=es
http://localhost/xyz?language=esdfsdf
```

I am redirected to errorpage

Cannot understand the issue with code.

Comment: FYI: It's called an *if statement*, there's no such thing as an "if loop".

Comment: Also, think it through slowly... *if X is not A __or__ is not B*... one of these will *always* apply.

Comment: First of all, there's no such thing as a "if loop", a loop is something that, well, loops, iterates, which an `if` statement doesn't. Secondly if you're serious about programming (in any language) i recommend you learn [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).

Answer (score 5):

Replace || by &&.

The reason :
You want to redirect only if this is not `en` AND not `es`.

Answer (score 4):

change the if statment to `&&` instead of `||` or your condition will be always false.

```
if(isset($_GET['language'])){
    if($_GET['language'] !== "en" && $_GET['language'] !== "es"){
        header('Location: /xyz/errorpage'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: _or your condition will be always false_ - not, it will be always true :-)

Answer (score 4):

You have bad condition, or better, operator.

Use `&&` instead of `||`, or `in_array()`.

```
if(($_GET['language'] !== "en") && ($_GET['language'] !== "es")) {
```

Using `in_array()` function:

```
if (!in_array($_GET['languge'], array('en', 'es'))) {
    header ();
}
```

Condition `if ($a != 'x' || $a != 'y')` is always `true`, first or the second part of condition has be true. There are no other ways.

Comment: which would be performing faster, in_array or operators?

Comment: @OMTheEternity: not sure, in_array is better to read while you will work with more than two languages. And imho it will be a little bit faster (when the function find `'en'` in array, returns true. When you have a chain of `&&`, PHP has to compare each one of them and than return soething).

Comment: It's not important which is faster.  Are you going to run this query a billion times a day? If not you've already spent 100 billion runs of the condition thinking about it.  in_array is easier to add to if you need it in the future.